# Is material set theory conservative over structural set theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

Suppose a statement $\phi$ that *doesn't* use the global $\in$-relation or the global $=$-relation in an essential way is provable in some [material](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory) set theory, say bounded Zermelo with choice. (So that the statement $\phi$ itself essentially is [structural](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) while, in theory, the intermediate steps in the proof of $\phi$ *might be material*, thus containing the global $\in$-relation or the global $=$-relation in an essential way!) Can it be proved that $\phi$ (or, rather, the translation of $\phi$ into the appropriate structural set theory) is nevertheless provable in some structural set theory, say ETCS, meaning that all the material intermediate steps can be eliminated?  (Note that since $\phi$ doesn't use the global $\in$-relation or the global $=$-relation in an essential way, such a translation should exist.)

Of course, in practice, most proofs are already structural. But who knows what crazy things could be done in theory by exploiting the global $\in$-relation?

I already know that ETCS and bounded Zermelo with choice are equiconsistent. Though related, it seems I'm asking for something stronger.

Comment: What is "global $\in$-relation" and "global $=$-relation", and what does it mean to (not) use them in an "essential way"?

Comment: It depends on the specific theories involved.

Comment: @Wojowu in material set theories like ZF you are allowed to use the $\in$ or $=$ relation for arbitrary sets (it makes sense to ask whether $2 \in \pi$ or $exp = \mathbb{Q}$). In a structual set theories it only makes sense to ask whether two elements of a same sets are equal, or whether an element of a set X belong a subset U of X. I think the concrete formulation of the question is "Given a statement in the language of, say, ETCS which can be proved - when translated - in bounded ZF, can it be proved in ETCS ?"

Comment: @Simon: In structural set theory it makes sense to ask "is $\sqrt2$ surjective?"

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure what is your point here ?  I guess if you work in a theory that identifies elements of a set with functions from the singleton then it does. is that what you mean ? In that case then that's definitely not a meaningless statement: It is about whether there exists other real number than $\sqrt{2}$, I think that's a question we might want to know the answer to !

Comment: @Simon: Yes, that wasn't a great example. You can ask if $\sqrt2$ and $e$ are isomorphic or what are the domain and range of $3$, and many other questions that *you* can cast in a way that makes sense, whereas an analyst will simply blink and tell you to stop talking nonsense... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wasn't casting any judgment of value on material vs structural set theories. I was just clarifying what is meant by "global $\in$ relation" and not using it as it seemed it was unclear. But If you want to go down that road again, I am pretty sure analyst are pretty happy to know that the range of $3$ only has one element, once you told them you are just calling 3 the function $* \mapsto 3$, which I think is a notation they would agree with ;-)

Comment: @Simon: I'm sorry if I'm somewhat aggressive here. My point here is that people treat this as a good reason to think that ZFC is not "worth the effort", and in a world where I repeatedly hear about how set theory "is dying out", repeating these claims that somehow structural set theory is "free of junk" is both false and damaging to an entire field of mathematics. So I get a bit anxious when I see it.

Comment: I've never seen an example of a "junk theorem" in ETCS that doesn't involve an abuse of notation. That's despite how often this topic comes up on MO, and despite all the comments it tends to attract. I don't believe such examples exist.

Comment: ETCS (and the apparatus around it) sometimes produces statements that are perfectly meaningful but phrased in unusual language. This is *not* the same as a "junk theorem" - a term I don't like, but which I take to mean "theorem about meaningful entities that is only true because of arbitrary hidden conventions".

Comment: For comparison, consider sequences. Everyone defines a sequence in a set $X$ as a function $\mathbb{N} \to X$. So officially, we could ask whether a sequence in $X$ is surjective. No one uses that language; we say "exhaustive" or some such. But if we *did* say a sequence was surjective, it would be a meaningful statement phrased in unusual language. And the strange possibility of asking whether a sequence "is surjective" is not seen as a drawback of the formal definition of sequence.

Comment: In exactly the same way, ETCS defines an element of a set $X$ as a function $1 \to X$ (where $1$ is a fixed terminal set). Officially, we could ask whether an element of $X$ is surjective. No one uses that language, but it is a meaningful question ("is $x$ the only element of $X$?") phrased in an unusual way. The strange possibility of asking whether an element "is surjective" should not be seen as a drawback of the ETCS definition of element, any more than for sequences.

Comment: Generally, an $I$-indexed family of elements of a set $X$ is the same as a function $I \to X$ (and is usually *defined* that way). But we use different language for families and functions, even though they're formally identical. And that's fine -- we translate back and forth without a second thought. The case $I = \mathbb{N}$ is sequences; the case $I = 1$ is elements.

Comment: Final point for now: in my first comment, I said that I'd never seen anyone succeed in producing a "junk theorem" in ETCS *that doesn't involve an abuse of notation*. If you allow yourself to abuse notation, e.g. referring to an injection $i: A \to X$ as just "$A$", it's easy. But that says nothing about ETCS: in any mathematical context whatsoever, you can get meaningless statements by abusing notation in an unwise way.

Comment: @TomLeinster: I’d argue there are certainly “junk theorems” in ETCS (also in dependent type theories, and just about any other foundational system I’ve seen or can imagine).  Going into this carefully is too long for a comment — if you ask a new question and ping me here, I can give it as an answer there, or else by email if you’d rather!

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That's very mysterious of you, and I'll believe it when I see it. I've sent you an email asking for one example.

Answer (score 11):

This will obviously be highly dependent on the concrete theory you are considering. But overall the answer is yes.

The most general version of these results I'm aware of are in Mike Shulman's [Comparing material and structural set theories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05204.pdf). You'll find all the answer you want in this paper. But let me try to give you some pointers: I think the most relevant result here is lemma 9.1 which (roughly, see the paper for the details) says:

"Given $\mathbf{Set}$ ( a suitable pretopos, for eg. a model of ETCS) then the inclusion $\mathbb{S}\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{Set}) \to \mathbf{Set}$ is an equivalence if and only if every object of $\mathbf{Set}$ can be embedded into an extentional well founded graph"

where $\mathbb{V}$ denotes the construction described in Mike's paper that attach a material set theory to a structural theory and $\mathbb{S}$ takes a material set theory to its category of sets.

Any formula in $\phi$ in the language of a structural set theory is in particular a forumla in the 'language of categories' so is invariant by equivalence of categories. So, if the lemma applies, a formula $\phi$ is valid in $\mathbf{Set}$ if and only if it is valid in $\mathbb{S}\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{Set})$ that is exactly if the material translation of $\phi$ is valid in $\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{Set})$.

So if the material translation of $\phi$ is provable in the theory of $\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{Set})$ then it holds in $\mathbf{Set}$. If $\mathbf{Set}$ is a model of ETCS, then $\mathbb{V}(\mathbf{Set})$ satisfies Bounded Zermelo with choice ( and Mostowski principle and transitive closure, again, see mike's paper for the details). So that answer your question.

Note that, In the general case, the key condition is whether in $\mathbf{Set}$ every object can be embedded into an extentional well founded graph. Working with ETCS, or more generally if you have choice then this is really not a problem (e.g. put a well order on your set), but in more generality it might be problematic:

By construction material set theory (well founded and with transitive closure) always construct a set as a subset of an extentional well founded graph (its transitive closure with the $\in$ relation), so if your structural set theory cannot do this as well, this gives a counter-example to the question you are asking, as the existence of such an embedding is a meaningful structural statement.

Maybe there is a generalization of this construction that allows to get non well founded set theories that would go arround this problem, but I am not aware of this having been studied (?).

Comment: There is certainly a generalization to non-well-founded set theories, although I don't know if it's been written down.  However, it doesn't go around the problem completely, because you still have to impose some extensionality conditions on the graphs, and AFAIK there is still no way to prove structurally that every set can be embedded into such a graph, even though the class of graphs is now somewhat wider.